# Is there any point for using react-test-renderer with react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I can't understand why some tutorials use `react-test-renderer` with `react-testing-library`,

As i understand, `react-test-renderer` is a library that can create a pure object from a react component and convert it to json snapshot!

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

function Link(props) {
  return <a href={props.page}>{props.children}</a>;
}

const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
  <Link page="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</Link>
);

expect(testRenderer).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Now, i can do the same with `Testing library`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react;

test('create link snapshot', () => {
    const {container} = 
       render(<Linkpage="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</Link>);
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

I really can't understand why i need to use `react-test-renderer` along with `testing-library`, what can `react-test-renderer` do `testing-library` can't?

Comment: From what I've understood of the RTL docs, RTL is a lot of syntactic sugar around/over react-test-renderer, that being said, in my 3+ years in react I've not ever used react-test-renderer (save for maybe some custom react hooks unit testing). Previously I used jestjs/enzyme before jumping ship over to jestjs/RTL. Never looked back.

Comment: "why i need to use react-test-renderer along with testing-library" who says you need? Can you provide an example of using test renderer with the testing-library?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko some tutorials on youtube used both, i used them blindly following the tutorials but after reading about all testing libraries i figured out that it was crazy to use them together

Comment: MB those tutorials are showing the difference between them: here you have lightweight "unittest-like" render to object, here you have full render to DOM.

Comment: @DrewReese
i think RTL is away more than just a syntactic sugar for RTR, both work differently, RTR doesn't depend on DOM, RTL depend of DOM node queries, as i understood

Comment: @CodeEagle Hmm, I think you're correct... RTL says it builds on top of DOM Testing Library. I think I may've conflated the two based on RTL's [API](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api), namely the `act` method.

Comment: @DrewReese No problem, plenty of libraries there, too confusing :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko
You asked for an example, this is one of them, you can start watching after 16:00

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between enzyme, ReactTestUtils and react-testing-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152562/difference-between-enzyme-reacttestutils-and-react-testing-library)

Comment: @slideshowp2 i really understand the difference between all of them, but i have watched many tutorials that use testing library with react-test-renderer which confused me about the use of all of them, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Renderer

**react-test-renderer** is the most basic utility library that is shipped with React. From React documentation:

> This package provides a React renderer that can be used to render React components to pure JavaScript objects, without depending on the DOM or a native mobile environment.

---

### @testing-library/react

**React Testing Library** is part of the testing-library family, is built on top of **react-test-renderer** and is made to be a rather lightweight solution.

It provides utilities to test React and follow the idea of avoiding [implementations details tests](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details).

---

### Enzyme

The **Enzyme** is much more complex and heavy. It gives you many more functionalities but not only for the best: it becomes too easy to do implementation details testing.

*Note that: **Testing implementation details is fundamentally bad**
*Note that: **Enzyme is dead. (There will be no React 18 support). [Read more Here](https://dev.to/wojtekmaj/enzyme-is-dead-now-what-ekl)**

---

### Read More:

You can visit the [link](https://morintd.medium.com/react-testing-understand-and-chose-the-right-tools-858236d3c4e1) below to read more about these tools and their pros and cons. you can also see a complete comparison and experience after using them over years.

https://morintd.medium.com/react-testing-understand-and-chose-the-right-tools-858236d3c4e1