# Which Enzyme adapter works with React 17?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have a React app, and I want to start writing unit tests with Enzyme. Enzyme's [documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) discusses versions of React up to 16.

In `src/setupTests.js` I currently have

```js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

But my app uses React version 17.0.1. **What enzyme adapter is there for React 17?**

Answer (score 113, accepted):

> **What enzyme adapter is there for React 17?**

If you have **React version 17**, you can use this [unofficial adapter for React 17 for enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17).

```js
// src/setupTests.js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2429) for more information on the unofficial adapter.

Comment: 2022 and still no released adapter for React 17

Comment: @Andrew Enzyme is in a dying stage, just go for react-testing-library

Comment: @PouyaAtaei: Except that `react-testing-library` is designed to AVOID classical unit testing.  It's creator writes: "Tests which [test implementation details] ultimately prevent you from modifying and refactoring the component without changing its tests." I write unit tests IN ORDER TO test implementation details. I change a component by first changing its unit tests (so that they fail) and then making the altered tests pass. That is why TDD exists.

Comment: @TomStambaugh you should not test implementation details, that's naive. You should aim to test  the behaviour of your component, thus if you correctly abstracted a component and behaviour changes... you can capture it.... testing implementation details outweights the benefits that testing provides, is incredibly fragile, and may not even capture the requirements correctly..

Answer (score 6):

I tried with unofficial adapter '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17' and it works fine. **Thanks @super Jade.**

1. clear the npm cache (clearing this may make npm slower, but give it a try).

- `npm cache verify` and then `npm cache clean --force`

2. remove your

- `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

3. update npm dependencies in your `package.json` with `"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5","@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.1","react": "^17.0.1","react-dom": "^17.0.1",`
4. `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`
5. as **@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17** mentioned making a change in the test file.

- import Adapter from `'@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';`
- configure `({ adapter: new Adapter() });`

Comment: You no longer need `--legacy-peer-deps` flag when installing `@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17` as of version `0.6.0`. Proceed as normal! :)

Comment: what should the ``package.json`` file look like?

Answer (score 5):

add this code in setupTests.js file

```
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've tried [@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17) for React 17, and it does work just fine.

After using `npm install --save-dev @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17` you also need to set up enzyme to use the adapter you want it to use, you do so by adding the top level configure API:

```
/* src/setupTests.js */
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```