# why am getting npm ERROR ! while npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I was trying npm install i got the error as -

```
# npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: isomorphic@4.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0-0" from enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.6
npm ERR! node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16
npm ERR!   enzyme-adapter-react-16@"^1.15.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried using npm install --force and npm install --legacy--peer-deps
then got the error as -

```
# npm install --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

also tried changing max min timeout ... but didnt work
when search on google i found some yarn cmd , but am not sure what yarn does ..
can anyone please help me out ....

Comment: have you tried changing your network connection?

Comment: yes getting same errors - @geeky01adarsh

Answer (score 0):

For 1st problem:

It's package dependencies problem.
It's look like you use React 17 (Found: react@17.0.2). But module enzyme-adapter-react-16 need React 16.

Solution: downgrade react to version 16 or change enzyme-adapter-react-16 to enzyme-adapter-react-17.

Comment: now getting - # npm update
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: isomorphic@4.0.2
npm ERR! Found: antd@4.24.12
npm ERR! node_modules/antd
npm ERR!   antd@"^4.16.12" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer antd@"^5.0.1" from @ant-design/compatible@5.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ant-design/compatible
npm ERR!   @ant-design/compatible@"^5.1.1" from the root project

Comment: It's looks like you have dependencies problem with antd: isomorphic@4.0.2 required antd version 4, but installed antd@5

Answer (score 0):

From the [enzyme-adapter-react-16](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-adapter-react-16) documentation, we know:

> At the moment, Enzyme has adapters that provide compatibility with `React 16.x`, `React 15.x`, `React 0.14.x` and `React 0.13.x`.

| Enzyme Adapter Package | React semver compatibility |
| --- | --- |
| enzyme-adapter-react-16 | ^16.4.0-0 |

But the `react` version is `^17.0.2` in your project, which is an incompatible version.

Two solutions:

- Downgrading the `react` package to the `^16.4.0` version.
- Use [@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17) package, an unofficial adapter for React 17 for Enzyme.

Unfounaly, there is no official adapter for `React 17.x` and `React 18.x`

Further reading:

- [Which Enzyme adapter works with React 17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658031/which-enzyme-adapter-works-with-react-17)
- [issue#2564](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/pull/2564)